# What is the difference between TAB and <tab>?

Tags: key-bindings

I was reading the the [documentation](http://capitaomorte.github.io/yasnippet/snippet-expansion.html) for Yasnippet mode, when I came to the section where the trigger key is defined:

It seems like Yasnippet minor mode defines the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key to run `yas-expand` using:

```el
(define-key yas-minor-mode-map (kbd "<tab>") 'yas-expand)
(define-key yas-minor-mode-map (kbd "TAB") 'yas-expand)
```

What is the difference between `<tab>` and `TAB`?
(I tried to google this but I could not find a clear description)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Although Emacs usually translates `<tab>` (the single key) to
<kbd>TAB</kbd> (<kbd>C-i</kbd>), you can bind <kbd><tab></kbd>
and <kbd>TAB</kbd> to different things:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<tab>") #'proced)
(global-set-key (kbd "TAB") #'indent-for-tab-command)
```

Comment: I see, but why do Yasnippet need to define both `<tab>` and `TAB`?

Comment: @HåkonHægland if you happen to bind them to different commands on the global-map, emacs stops translating one to the other (even on minor mode maps), so yasnippet bind both just in case.

Comment: @Malabarba So if you define both `<tab>` and `TAB`, the only way to run the command associated with `TAB` is to type `C-i` ?

Comment: If you bind `<tab>` to a different command than what you bind `TAB` to, then what you get when you hit the "Tab" key depends on which/what it sends to Emacs. If it sends `C-i` (aka `TAB`) then you get the `TAB` binding. If it sends `<tab>` then you get its binding. (And yes, you can always hit `C-i` to get the `TAB` binding.)

Comment: More historical information about the different `TAB` keys are given by `StreakyCobra` in [this](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/4024) spacemacs github issue. You may want to include some of that information in your answer.

Comment: Thanks @HåkonHægland, [this comment](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/4024#issuecomment-161122099) in that issue was the level of detail I was looking for! So if you want the binding to work for both GUI and terminal, use `TAB`, or if GUI-only, use `<tab>`.