# Force keymap to ignore (kbd <tab>) and [tab] even though TAB is defined

Tags: key-bindings, keymap

I found that when I press the tab key, the command I have bound to <kbd>C-i</kbd> gets run (somewhat unsurprisingly). I would like to keep this command bound to <kbd>C-i</kbd> but run a different one when pressing the tab key. I have found that I can do this within a keymap by defining `(kbd <tab>)`

Thanks to [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/654/6761) Emacs.SE post, I found which keymap is responsible for it and that there is a global binding for tab. The keymap doesn't have `(kbd <tab>)` bound, but it's translated instead of falling through to the global binding.

How do I get it to fall through?

Comment: `(kbd "<tab>")` and `[tab]` are completely identical.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/9631/what-is-the-difference-between-tab-and-tab/9634#comment14342_9634) comment provides a solution: bind the global `(kbd "TAB")` and `(kbd "<tab>")` to different things and Emacs will stop translating the keybinding.