# How to distinguish C-i from TAB?

Tags: key-bindings, keymap

Normally, for historic reasons, emacs treats the `TAB` keycode and the `C-i` key as the same, cf. [the emacs lisp documentation on function keys](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Function-Keys.html) or [abo-abo's answer on the question "What is the difference between TAB and ?"](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/9634/448).

> **NOTE:** In this post, keycodes are `TAB`, `<tab>`, and `C-i`; <kbd>tab</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd> on the other hand are the *physical* keys on the keyboard.
>
> However, at the moment, emacs treats the `TAB` and `C-i` as the same thing, i.e. `(equal (kbd "TAB") (kbd "C-i"))` -> `t`.

However, since we are no longer living in the stoneage of computing I find this **extremely** annoying. There's a few suggestions out there what can be done to work around this, e.g.

- ["How do I bind a command to C-i without changing TAB?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792326/how-do-i-bind-a-command-to-c-i-without-changing-tab)

  - [Trey's Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1792482/1396507) did not work for my, the variable `local-function-key-maps` is not changed. Modifying it to use `delete` rather than `delq` does result in a modified variable but it does not bring resolve ... <kbd>tab</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> are still the same.
  - [Translating to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2253044/1396507) [the hyper map](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11319885/1396507) seems like a 1980s workaround ... I might want to use <kbd>Hyper</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> as well.
- [Using the `input-decode-map` to map <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> to some post-ASCII control code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32279388/1396507) is almost what I'm looking for. Except that it does not work properly with the `kbd` macro meaning that one must modify all bits of source code that will bind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>. Arguably this is the best solution given that all source code is modified properly.
- Using `(kbd "<tab>")` for <kbd>tab</kbd> and `(kbd "C-i")` (which translates to `(kbd "TAB")` i.e. the `\t` literal) for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> **does work** but you'd have to modify *all* source files which use the wrong kind of <kbd>tab</kbd> [Read: the keycode `TAB`] which is annoying.
  This has been suggested e.g. [in a github issue](https://github.com/bling/evil-jumper/issues/8) and [on emacs.sx as well](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/9631/what-is-the-difference-between-tab-and-tab).

None of these solutions seem real solutions, I'd rather consider them workarounds or hacks (of the existing *bug*).

> Is there a way out there to **force** emacs to map <kbd>tab</kbd> to `(kbd "<tab>")` and `(kbd "TAB")` while <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> is mapped to `(kbd "C-i")` short of modyfing the emacs source code?
>
> This approach should be completely invisible to the user, meaning that the <kbd>tab</kbd> like keycodes `<tab>` and `TAB` should map to one binding whilst the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> like keycode `C-i` should map to another binding.

On a less serious note: Any emacs developers here who can comment whether this will be changed / fixed in the emacs source code at some point?

Comment: Note that `TAB` and `C-i` (the codes, not the keys) are one and the same by definition of `TAB`.

Comment: @Stefan That's why I added the _Note_ thing. I'm going to edit the post and put it in there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to bind C-i as different from TAB?](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/220/how-to-bind-c-i-as-different-from-tab)

Comment: IMO, this question is not a duplicate, because it wants to relocate all keybindings defined on TAB (even those from external packages), to use <tab> instead. While the other question was asking how to differentiate them in your own code.

Comment: My suggestion would be to advise `kbd` to translate TAB as [tab]. It just won't work for the preloaded parts of Emacs.

Comment: @Malabarba That was what the previous question asked for, too. It got an answer that only covered part of the job, but that doesn't make the question less of a duplicate. I've now posted a more thorough answer.

Answer (score 29):

The future is long gone, and the stone age of computing is just about to come.  All text terminals I know still send the exact same byte-sequence to Emacs for <kbd>C-i</kbd> as for <kbd>TAB</kbd>, so the original need to "unify" them is still very much with us.

The input-decode-map (à la `(define-key input-decode-map "\C-i" [C-i])`) is probably about as good as it gets right now.

As Emacs ex-maintainer, I'd welcome a better solution to this problem, so as to free up the <kbd>C-i</kbd> (and <kbd>C-m</kbd> and <kbd>C-[</kbd>) keys under GUIs (probably make them "reserved for the user").  But I don't know how to do that without causing lots of problems with existing packages.

Comment: [The bronze age has arrived, but so far in xterm only](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/220/how-to-bind-c-i-as-different-from-tab/20290#20290)

Comment: Wonder what kind of keyboards do you use? With the typical QWERT keyboards the distinction is just apparent, and not being able to distinguish these keys is such a pain...