# How can I use Helm File Finder to copy a file path to a buffer?

Tags: helm, kill-ring

Is there a way, in the buffer launched from `helm-find-files`, to copy a file path to the kill ring?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try `C-c TAB` when you have the file highlighted. This will yank the path into the current buffer, which might be an undesired side effect, but as long as you do `helm-find-files` from the buffer you want to use it in, you should be fine.

Comment: The key binding of `helm-copy-to-buffer` is `C-c C-i`, however, `C-c TAB` works as well (though I don't know why).

Comment: @xuchunyang hmm, now that you mention it I see in `helm.el` that `helm-copy-to-buffer` is indeed bound to `C-c C-i`, but `helm-help` lists the binding as `C-c TAB` with no mention of `C-c C-i`...

Comment: I see: Emacs doesn't distinguish between `C-i` and `TAB` according to http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17509/properly-distinguish-ctrli-and-tab

Comment: @xuchunyang Ha! That is interesting! Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: This copies the absolute path - is there some way to copy the relative path?

Answer (score 15):

If yanking the path into the current buffer is not acceptable, use `C-u C-c C-k`, which invokes `helm-kill-selection-and-quit`.

From the documentation of `helm-kill-selection-and-quit`:

> Store display value of current selection to kill ring.
>   With a prefix arg set to real value of current selection.
>   Display value is what you see in `helm-buffer' and real value
>   is what is used to perform actions.

Tested using helm 1.9.1.

Comment: Nice, I thought about adding `helm-kill-selection-and-quit`, but I thought it  just gave you the file name. I didn't realize that with a prefix argument you get the path!

Comment: This works, but how would anyone ever find this!