# How to distinguish C-m from RETURN?

Tags: key-bindings

When in javascript mode trying to use `C-c C-m i` get an error saying  "`C-c RET` is undefined?"

What makes Emacs believe I am pressing `RET`?

How can i properly make this keybinding work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Properly distinguish Ctrl+i and Tab](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17509/properly-distinguish-ctrli-and-tab)

Comment: Same problem, different entry point, I think it would be nice to keep both questions around for people coming from different searches.

Comment: [Meta question about whether this question is a duplicate](http://meta.emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/368/same-problem-different-entry-point-is-it-a-duplicate)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to bind C-i as different from TAB?](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/220/how-to-bind-c-i-as-different-from-tab)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Emacs "thinks" that `C-m` is `RET` because "Control M" is the ASCII control character "carriage return". Even though this reason is "historical" Emacs can run in a terminal and so it needs to support the way terminals *still* work now.

Try opening a terminal window, typing "`ls`", and pressing `C-m`. You will see that it is interpreted as "return", even though you are **not** in Emacs.

See [Control character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character) on Wikipedia for details about control characters.

To distinguish `C-m` from `RET` in a GUI Emacs, one could change `C-i` to `C-m` in [**@nispio**'s answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/221/2355):

```el
(define-key input-decode-map [?\C-m] [C-m])

;; now we can do this:

(defun my-command ()
  (interactive)
  (message "C-m is not the same as RET any more!"))

(global-set-key (kbd "<C-m>") #'my-command)
```

See also

- [How to distinguish C-i from TAB?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/17509/2355), which is very closely related.
- [How to bind C-i as different from TAB?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/220/2355) and [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/221/2355) in particular.

Comment: This is brilliant, thank you. Now I can have `C-m` as a prefix map for multiple-cursors.

Comment: How come this issue doesn't show up with the other control characters?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why, but the accepted answer did not work for me. Maybe it is because of how I declare my key bindings.

I use `bind-keys` like this...

```lisp
    (bind-keys :map my-mode-map ...)
```

to bind keys, then I activate my-mode so that my key declarations always have precedence. Using my own mode is new, but I always used `bind-keys`.

In bind-keys I include the following:

```lisp
    ([return] . newline) ;; needed to distinguish from C-m
```

Looking at key declaration help, I do not believe that assigning `[return]` to `newline` changes the function of the return key, but declaring `[return]` causes the `Return` key to become different than `Control-M`, allowing me to declare `[C-m]` later in the same bind-keys command and the two declaratoins are unique.

I use the same technique to separate `[tab]` from `[C-i]`, first binding `[tab]`, then binding `[C-i]` in the same `bind-keys` statement.