# Bind all C-x C-m sequences properly

Tags: key-bindings

I'm trying to open a file with a given encoding and running into the problem that C-m is the same as RET.  There is an answer [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/20240/how-to-distinguish-c-m-from-return).  However, I don't want to bind a specific function; I want to restore all C-x C-m key bindings to their intended behavior; so, the next time I look up how to do something, it just works.

This raises the question of why there even are C-x C-m bindings if they don't work.  Note I'm assuming this [documentation](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ChangingEncodings) is correct.  I don't know how to look up the command for the binding.  If I use C-h k to describe the command, I'm still stuck with the problem of how to type C-x C-m!

I also looked at [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17509/how-to-distinguish-c-i-from-tab), but I'm not clear if he's saying it can't be done, or is it only in a terminal that it's a problem?  I'm only using emacs in a GUI; I can't remember the last time I used it in a terminal.  I'm open to workarounds, such as using a different key.  The trouble with this is I won't remember it has been remapped unless I use it frequently...

Comment: Documentation usually uses `C-m` and `RET` interchangably. And usually they are interchangable. Are you asking how to undo the effect of `(define-key input-decode-map [?\C-m] [C-m])`?

Comment: No, you just answered my question.  I didn't understand they are effectively the same thing.  I don't need to do anything except not look at the command in the minibufffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Note I'm assuming this [documentation](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ChangingEncodings) is correct.

It's basically correct, it sometimes puts `C-m` instead of `RET`.  In a default configured Emacs those are the same anyway and you might find it easier to type `C-x C-m` than `C-x <return>`.  Note that the official documentation uses `RET` uniformly in this case, [`(emacs) Text Coding`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Text-Coding.html):

> <kbd>C-x RET f coding RET</kbd>
>
> Use coding system coding to save or revisit the file in
>   the current buffer (`set-buffer-file-coding-system`).

---

> I also looked at this [answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17509/how-to-distinguish-c-i-from-tab), but I'm not clear if he's saying it can't be done, or is it only in a terminal that it's a problem?

That's explaining that in a terminal, it's not possible to have `C-m` and `RET` be different.  You *can* make them different in a GUI Emacs, but you probably shouldn't.

Comment: +1 for referencing the doc and for "*but you probably shouldn't*."