# How to bind C-S-m and avoid S-RET?

Tags: key-bindings, modifier-key, control-characters

I am trying to rebind `kmacro-start-macro` and `kmacro-end-macro` to `C-m` and `C-S-m`.
But I am having some issues because of `C-m` being equivalent to `RET`, the ASCII control character "carriage return".

In [the answer to *How to distinguish C-m from RETURN?* question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/20241/6957), shows how to make `C-m` binding work with:

```
(define-key input-decode-map [?\C-m] [C-m])
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-m>") 'kmacro-start-macro)
```

But I am not able to bind `C-S-m`. With:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-S-m>") 'kmacro-end-macro)
```

Whenever I use `describe-key` on `C-S-m`, it shows:

```
RET (translated from S-RET) runs the command newline (found in
global-map), which is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
‘simple.el’.

It is bound to RET.
```

How can I bind `C-S-m`?

Answer (score 3):

While writing the answer and doing some tests, I found how to bind `C-S-m` in a similar fashion as `C-m`, escaping Shift key with `\S`.

These lines made it work:

```
(define-key input-decode-map [?\C-\S-m] [C-S-m])
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-S-m>") 'kmacro-end-macro)
```