# How can I bind vertico-insert to toggle in the list?

Tags: key-bindings, find-file, vertico

I am using `find-file` with [`vertico`](https://github.com/emacs-straight/vertico). After running `find-file` and typing filename and when I press `<TAB>` it selects the current line.

```markdown
TAB runs the command vertico-insert (found in vertico-map), which is an
interactive byte-compiled Lisp function in ‘vertico.el’.

It is bound to TAB.

(vertico-insert)
```

[image]

Instead, is it possible to bing `<TAB>` as to toggle inside the list of find filenames?

Comment: maybe `(define-key vertico-map (kbd "<tab>") 'vertico-next)`

Comment: @roomworoof it did not helped , like it still remains as `(vertico-insert)`:-(

Comment: As for this setting, I tried it in my environment and it worked, but I also have had the same experience as you, I could not overwrite keymap in another case. I wonder what the cause is.

Comment: @roomworoof Its impossible to find the cause of it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `TAB` instead of `<tab>` and it will work.

```lisp
(define-key vertico-map (kbd "TAB") 'vertico-next)
```

Since `TAB` (not `<tab>`) is used in the source `(defvar-keymap vertico-map ...)`, this should overwrite it correctly.
I just learned for the first time that `TAB` and `<tab>` are different things...

1. `<tab>` = <kbd>Tab</kbd> (GUI only)
2. `TAB` = <kbd>C-i</kbd> = <kbd>Tab</kbd> (Terminal, or GUI if `<tab>` is not set)

They say it's for historical reasons, see [StreakyCobra's comment](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/4024#issuecomment-161122099) (referred by another questioner @Håkon Hægland on this site: [What is the difference between TAB and <tab>?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/9631/what-is-the-difference-between-tab-and-tab))

Comment: It works! Not sure but can it toggle cycle like back to top if the selected line is at bottom?

Comment: `(setq vertico-cycle t)`?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to go back to the prompt line by setting `vertico-cycle`, define another function like this:

```lisp
(defun my-vertico-next (&optional n)
  "Circulate without returning to the prompt line"
  (interactive "p")
  (let ((index (+ vertico--index (or n 1))))
    (vertico--goto
     (if (= vertico--total 0) -1 (mod index vertico--total)))))

(define-key vertico-map (kbd "TAB") 'my-vertico-next)
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the seconds answer as well!