# Using TAB to flip between two windows

Tags: key-bindings, tabs

I have set TAB to flip between two windows using:-

(global-set-key (kbd "TAB") 'other-window)

This works sometimes, but not always. How should I define it?

Comment: Say what "works" means, and say when it doesn't work. And start Emacs using `emacs -Q`, to remove your init file from the problem space.

Comment: It does not work in the *GNU Emacs* or *Directory* buffers.

Comment: Not clear. Provide a recipe, please. And buffers are not windows.

Answer (score 2):

It could possibly be caused due to sometimes the key being understood as `<tab>` and other times as `TAB`.

Switch to `fundamental-mode`. Try,

1. `C-h k C-i`: This should get you `TAB`.
2. `C-h k tabkey`: This may get you `TAB (translated from <tab>)`.

One way then is to,

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "<tab>") #'other-window)
(global-set-key (kbd "TAB") #'other-window)
```

For the difference between `TAB` and `<tab>` [read more here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/9631/25462).

Answer (score 1):

> (global-set-key (kbd "TAB") 'other-window)

As @scribe said, with bindings containing Tab, Backspace, Escape, etc. you may get the syntax wrong so you can read more about the use of angle brackets, and the differences in general.

> This works sometimes, but not always. How should I define it?

It's hard to guess if you don't provide more details but one reason why `other-window` may behave "work sometimes" (i.e. changing window usually but sometimes, even if another window is present, not changing to it) is because of the `no-other-window` window parameter: windows such as temporary side windows (e.g. output of some command) work this way - cycling through windows will ignore them. Using `ignore-window-parameters` can alter this behavior.

Furthermore, bindings for functions like `other-window` (bindings with which you cycle through buffers/windows) may at some point "stop working" because you ended up in a buffer which overrides your keybinding.

By the way, you may consider leaving TAB alone (so you can use its default behavior), and instead using a prefix like:

```
(keymap-global-set "M-<tab>" 'other-window)
```

This uses the new key binding syntax (Emacs 29) as an example but should work exactly like `global-set-key`